# Intercept-Url and filters

Tags: java, spring, filter, spring-security

I'm currently working with Spring 3.0.4 and Spring Security 3.0.2 (latest stable release at the moment). I'm kind of struggling migrating from Spring 2.5 to this new version, but that's a different subject.

The real question is coming, inside the `<http>` tag you can put the `<intercept-url>`, but it seems like it can also be used inside Security Filters (as seen here : [Core web filters](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html)).

Can someone tell me the difference between these two? Why using it inside the http tag instead of inside in a security filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<http>` tag is a convenient way to configure security filters. When you use it, you typically don't need to configure individual filters.

However, in the complex cases you may configure filters manually as shown in the docs you referenced.

So, they do basically the same thing, but `<http>` tag is simplier and therefore it's a preferred way to configure Spring Security.

Comment: So it would do the same thing right? I can take any example which use the intercept-url in the filters tag and put it in the http tag and it have the same behavior.

Comment: @Frank: I think so, though I'm not familiar with configuring `<intercept-url>`s in the filters.